# Mathematical union of a QList<int>?

Tags: qt, list, math, union

I have a collection of `QList<int>`'s that I need to calculate the union of. Is there a built in function anywhere that does this for me?

If not, are there any special considerations that I should make when implementing this myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could convert each `QList` into a `QSet` with `Qlist::toSet()` and then just add each `QSet` together using `QSet::operator+`. This will give you the union but it will be in a random order.

Comment: Thanks! After realizing that there was a QSet, I can use that internally instead of QList and save a couple steps.

Comment: No problem. If the lack of ordering is an issue then bear in mind that if you use a plain old `std::set` you will automatically get them ordered from lowest to highest.

Comment: Ordering is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you maintain the lists ordered you can use `set_union` from STL's `<algorithm>` to create the union.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/